# MySQL source command contacting remote host

Tags: mysql, sql, import

sorry if this has been asked before and/or is dead stupid, but I couldn't really find what I was really looking for.

I want to populate a fresh, empty MySQL DB using .sql scripts. Normally I simply log into mysql, switch to my desired DB and use `source /path/to/script.sql` in order to load the SQL script into the db. This works fine, if my mySQL server is on the same machine as the scripts, but I'm having problems if the hosts are different.

So, is there a parameter for the `source` command to issue a remote host?
Or is the wise option to simply `scp` the .sql file in question to the DB host?

PS: I know you can also do a `mysql -h host -u user -p somedb < /path/to/script.sql` but I normally prefer the source method, as I sometimes in the past did not get all the output from mysql when using this option compared to `source`.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: No. `source` is purely for local operations. I've never tried, but you COULD try using an NFS path, e.g. `source remotemachine:/path/to/file`, but I doubt it'd work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no option in the `SOURCE` to reference a remote host. It's a reference relative to the local system.

So, yes **scp** the file to the remote host. Either that, or you'd need the remote file system mounted (e.g. NFS, or a mapped drive letter in Windows) so it appears as a local file system.

Comment: Thanks.. so I'll simply `scp` them.